# Binary (or STK3700 repl) file doesn't work properly in Renode project

Tags: embedded, renode

I ran some straightforward code for setting an LED in Simplicity Studio, then loaded the binary file into Renode, however, whenever I try to read the status of the LED in question, it returns false, even though it should be on and returning true.

The GPIO ports in the repl file are set according to the documentation.

I'm not sure what's wrong. The code should be good, I have tested it on hardware, maybe it's the STK3700 repl files that are at fault? I got them off of this GitHub link:

https://github.com/renode/renode/blob/master/platforms/boards/silabs/stk3700.repl

The code that sets LED0 (again, this is tested, just posting it in case it's needed):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"

int main(void)
{
  /* Chip errata */
  CHIP_Init();

CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO,1);

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1) {

      GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortE,2, gpioModePushPull, 1);
  }
}
```

Here is the Renode process I used for testing, that should be returning true:

```
Renode, version 1.14.0.34213 (81da46c1-202308081855)

(monitor) mach create "test"
(test) machine LoadPlatformDescription @platforms/boards/silabs/stk3700.repl 
(test) sysbus LoadBinary @C:/code/renode_test.bin 0x000
(test) start
Starting emulation...
(test) sysbus.gpioPort.led0 State
False
```

I've tried other test methods, but regardless of the code I write I don't get the desired output.

Comment: You have asked that same question at https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/1bilue4/renode_stk3700/ and there provided additional diagnostics not shown here.

Comment: "_I've tried other test methods, but regardless of the code I write I don't get the desired output._" - unless you exhibit those methods, that is not useful information and should either be omitted or expanded.

Answer (score 0):

`GPIO_PinModeSet` configures a GPIO pin, and need only be done once, before the loop.  You have no `GPIO_PinOutSet`, `GPIO_PinOutClear` or `GPIO_PinOutToggle` to actually assert the pin state.

Whether that would light the LED or not on real hardware would depend on how the LED is connected, and the initial state of the output.  Inverted logic is common; low for on.

It is always a good idea to use a blinking LED as an "alive" indication, a static state proves nothing, other than you have power.